# python firebase query by document ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase

If I want to query firebase documents under specific collection, how can I skip query some of document ID?

What I expected was

```
from firebase_admin import firestore

db = firestore.client()
skip_id = ["3zbBeHVvMY2aSfUM2mSL", "Xsa4cJOkIZbMkuYEGrLd", "kePiLfd7f9Lx99hSV9FM"]
docs = db.collection('my_collection').where("id", "not in", skip_id)
```

but it seems the above code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.where("id", "not in", skip_id)` means that you're filtering on a field named `id` in the document data, not on the document ID.

If you want to filter on the document ID, you can use the special `"__name__"` marker, or with `firestore_v1.field_path.FieldPath.document_id()`.

Also see:

- Issue [#153](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/153) on the `python-firestore` repo.
- The documentation on [FieldPath](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/field_path.html)
- Mentions of [`__name__`](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/search?q=__name__) and [`document_id`](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/search?q=document_id) in the `python-firestore` repo

Comment: May I ask how you import firestore_v1?

Comment: From the GitHub link that seems to be `from google.cloud import firestore_v1`, but I have no idea if that's correct.

Comment: well it seems like `firestore_v1.field_path.FieldPath.document_id()` is equal to `__name__`, and I tried `db.collection('my_collection').where("__name__", "not-in", ["3zbBeHVvMY2aSfUM2mSL"]).get()`, then I got an error:
` 400 __key__ filter value must be a Key`

Comment: Doesn't the import work though. Chris who was an engineer on the product at the time, got it working here https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/153#issuecomment-676552212 and from the code I checked the tests in the repo still run that code.