Query Firebase for "not-in document_id" in Python
I have an array with some document ids to avoid on my search. I am trying to run the query by using the FieldPath.document_id() but I am getting the __key__ filter value must be a Key. Is there any way to solve it?
Here's a snippet:
from firebase_admin import firestore
from google.cloud.firestore_v1.field_path import FieldPath

blocked_ids = ['123123','232323']

db = firestore.AsyncClient()
query_ref = db.collection('items').document('some-id-here').collection('other-items')
items = await query_ref.where(FieldPath.document_id(), "not-in", blocked_ids)

When i am printing FieldPath.document_id(), i am getting __name__.
I took a look at some other questions here and it seems like it's working for some.
Python firestore collection query order by document_id
Query firestore database for document id
How to use Firestore DocumentID __name__ in query

Did you try passing "__name__" as the field name?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751574/python-firebase-query-by-document-id

@FrankvanPuffelen yes, but its resulting in the same error. Like i wrote it, FieldPath.document_id() is returning __name__ as well.
